# How to achieve this guitar sound and what's the playing technique?

Tags: guitar, guitar-effects, sound-design

Does this guitar playing technique have a name which is being looped in this short preview? I don't know how to produce this kind of sound and which effects to use to achieve this. Any ideas?

https://www.dropbox.com/s/2u3jy1odgelppk1/cut.mp3

Comment: What guitar…? The predominant instrument sounds like a [Clavinet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clavinet).

Comment: Sorry, there's no guitar there! Clavinet, maybe. Listen to Superstition.

Comment: Ah ok, that's already good to know. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome! Just so you know, questions identifying songs, techniques, equipment, etc. are off-topic here, but might be a better fit at https://musicfans.stackexchange.com. Feel free to take the [tour](https://music.stackexchange.com/tour)! (Also: Clavinet is awesome.)

Comment: @AndyBonner Has Technique ID always been off-topic? I feel like we get a lot of technique questions, I would be surprised if those were all summarily off-topic. Seems weird, since learning technique is part of musical practice. I get why instrument and song ID questions are no good, but technique? OP is just asking how to make a certain sound. Seems like that ought to be permissible.

Comment: @user45266 I know, right? My guess is it falls under the "make sure question/answer can help future people" doctrine. In this case, the reference value of this question is "Hey, here's a sample of how a Clavinet sounds, but tagged with 'guitar.'" But surely one could imagine a technique question that should be on-topic; maybe we should discuss on Meta what it would look like.

Comment: A couple of relevant metas - https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2963/our-on-topic-page-currently-says-that-identifying-a-technique-is-off-topic ; https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3047/are-how-do-i-make-this-sound-questions-on-topic

Comment: @topoReinstateMonica Ah, thanks for doing my Meta homework for me. Shame we can't always have nice things...

Comment: @AndyBonner to be honest, I didn't read the whole tour - my bad. I just took a quick look at other questions, and thought this should fit here. However as I really thought it's kind of a guitar sound, I made my question unintentionally ontopic, but if I asked what kind of instrument it is, i'd be offtopic now. Luckily I got an answer, however not sure if this point in the rules is not too strict in a stackexchange called 'music'.